# Compiling Code for NodeMCU using Esplorer

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esplorer

I used the builtin compiler of Esplorer to compile .lua files in excess of 2KB and am unable to compile. NodeMCU resets and compilation aborted. Is there a way around to compile files in excess using Esplorer or any other way doing it outside Esplorer environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cross-compile on your PC before uploading. There's a chapter in the docs at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/upload/#compiling-lua-on-your-pc-for-uploading about that.

> If you install lua on your development PC or Laptop then you can use
>   the standard Lua compiler to syntax check any Lua source before
>   downloading it to the ESP8266 module. However, the nodemcu compiler
>   output uses different data types (e.g. it supports ROMtables) so the
>   compiled output cannot run on the ESP8266.
>
> Compiling source on one platform for use on another (e.g. Intel x38
>   Window to ESP8266) is known as cross-compilation and the nodemcu
>   firmware supports the compilation of luac.cross on *nix patforms which
>   have Lua 5.1, the Lua filesystem module (lfs), and the essential GCC
>   tools. Simply change directory to the firmware root directoy and run
>   the command:
>
> ```
> lua tools/cross-lua.lua
> ```
>
> This will generate a luac.cross executable in your root directory
>   which can be used to compile and to syntax-check Lua source on the
>   Development machine for execution under nodemcu lua on the ESP8266.